# What's a word for "quickly and not very carefully or thoroughly checking"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I want to say I just quickly check a paragraph of text and didn't find typo, but the checking is quick and not careful or thorough.  What is a good verb for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest [Cursorily](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cursorily). It means Performed with haste and scant attention to detail

Answer (score 9):

For a verb, consider *[skim](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/skim)*

> to read (a book) in a superficial or cursory manner

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single verb that adequately says all that you wrote in your original question. If you were expected to check for typos, I suggest saying it explicitly to avoid assumptions on the part of the person you're addressing: "I scanned the paragraph and didn't see any typos." (More formally: "I took a cursory look at the paragraph and didn't notice any typos.")

See a definition of "scan" here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scan?s=t 
(I'm new to this site and didn't post the definition for IP reasons; please let me know if this is a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Skim is good, but does not necessarily imply any checking.  I usually say something like, I gave it a once-over.